# Adding rows in Excel does not update VB code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have an excel 2010 spreadsheet with some VB code to auto-hide certain rows based on the selection. However, if I need to insert a row into my excel spreadsheet, it does not automatically update the vb code, as it does with formulas.

Here is an example of my code:

```
If Target.Address(False, False) = "B96" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "NO":  Rows("97:101").Hidden = True
        Case "YES": Rows("97:101").Hidden = False
    End Select
End If
```

So for example, if I insert a new row on my excel spreadsheet, at line 90, I would have expected the VB code to automatically update and the target.address would change to B97 and so on. It works for Excel Formulas so is there a way to make it work for the code too?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried playing with named ranges? This is a guess, buy maybe you could specify a named range instead of the actual row numbers. The range may auto-update when you insert a row into it.

Comment: VB code does not work like a formula but like PowerUser suggested, creating a named range might work.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you name (part of) the relevant range(e.g. A97:A101 ) to a Named Range, let's say OPTIONRNGE, then change your code to:

```
Case "NO":  Range("OPTIONRNGE").Rows.Hidden = True
Case "YES": Range("OPTIONRNGE").Rows.Hidden = False
```

etc. Then, if you insert rows, it will extend the range, and the code will still do the same thing. Named ranges are almost always a better idea than hardcoding ranges or row numbers in VBA.

Comment: Thank you....I'm still unclear if it would help. I have a number of these conditionality statements, and some of them have the same "Case" values, at different places in the spreadsheet. The reason I've listed them out separately is in case values change later on, its easier to fix up then if it affects other cells. Is there another way I can reference cells without specifying the values or range? Otherwise, where and how would I specify the range for those values so that I can reference them in the VB code?

Comment: "I'm still unclear if it would help" - I'm pretty sure it would! 
"Is there another way I can reference cells without specifying the values or range?" - No. You can refer to ranges directly e.g. Range("A1:A10"), or if you have named them, by name Range ("MYRANGE"). That's it

Comment: Thank you. I will go ahead and give this a try.